# c# 2010 and DLL

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

i need to use a oldest .dll driver (.dll is not .net) on c# 2010. I have a quick documentation about .dll that show me initdriver, closedriver, readdata ad so on ..

For istance INITDRIVER:

```
UNITE_RC rc = InitDriver(USHORT usNB_drv);
Parameters: usNB_drv: number or istance of driver that will be open
Return information:
OK:  well done
EBORNES: usNB_drv must be 1 or 2
EDRVAOPEN: driver yet open
```

So i try to find a solution on web and i think that i must use a DLLImport because i can't link dll in my project using reference or COM+. Someone can help me with some sample? Thank you a lot

Comment: What is "c# 2010"? And you tried to find a solution... for what? What is the question here?

Comment: Search for p/invoke .

Answer (score 2):

Well, we don't know what the `UNITE_RC` expands to. I'm going to assume that it expands to `int`. In which case your p/invoke declaration would be:

```
[DllImport(@"MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int InitDriver(ushort usNB_drv);
```

I'm also assuming that the calling convention is `cdecl` since the code you present does not state otherwise. Of course, it's conceivable that the actual code, perhaps in the `UNITE_RC` macro, perhaps elsewhere, specifies a different calling convention. To get to the bottom of this you really need to work with the C++ header file that is supplied with the library.

Another way to solve the problem would be to use a mixed mode C++/CLI wrapper around the library. That would let you call and link to the native code by the standard C++ mechanisms of including the header file, and supplying an import library (.lib) to the linker. You could then export a managed class (ref class in C++/CLI) for your C# code to consume. If the native code has more than a handful of functions that you need to call, this is the least error prone way to expose it to your C# code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have a doubt: i must use a DLLIMPORT call for each .dll methods?
For instance:
if i have "initdriver" and "closedriver" (with same parameters of initdriver)i shall write:
[DllImport(@"MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int InitDriver(ushort usNB_drv);
then 
[DllImport(@"MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int CloseDriver(ushort usNB_drv);


Thanks

Comment: Yes, one function declaration per imported function

Comment: Hi. I've try my c# project with [DllImport(@"MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int InitDriver(ushort usNB_drv). Then i calling InitDriver method but VS2010 raise a error ... can't find MyLib.dll ... The .dll was copied in the same folder of the .exe. I've try also to insert a long pathname of my .dll on DLLImport declaration but i receive the same error. Some idea? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the DLL has other dependencies that cannot be found. Use Dependency Walker to see what other dependencies are needed.